# How to get HK2 ServiceLocator in Jersey 2.12?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, hk2

I would like to create a singleton instance of a class that is not involved in Jersey as a Resource or Service and yet would like its dependencies injected from the Jersey ServiceLocator.

I can register this class manually in my ResourceConfig constructor, the ResourceConfig is then passed in to the Grizzly factory method like so:

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new DeviceServiceApplication();

LOGGER.info("Starting grizzly2...");
return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI,
                                                 resourceConfig, mServiceLocator);
```

The problem that remains is how to get a reference to the Jersey ServiceLocator so I can call createAndInitialize() to get my object with dependencies injected.  I see in previous Jersey versions there were constructor variants that expect an ApplicationHandler, which of course provides access to the service locator (how I initialise that is another matter).  You can also see I have tried passing in a parent ServiceLocator but of course the resolution happens from child -> parent locator and not in the other direction so asking the parent for my object fails because the Jersey @Contract and @Service types aren't visible here.

Do I need to use something other than GrizzlyHttpServerFactory ?  Do I give up and manually wire my singleton's dependencies?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to get a reference to `ServiceLocator` by registering a `ContainerLifecycleListener`.

In the `onStartup(Container container)` method, call `container.getApplicationHandler().getServiceLocator()`.

This example stores the reference as a member variable of `ResourceConfig` which you can use elsewhere via an accessor.

```
class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
    // won't be initialized until onStartup()
    ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    public MyResourceConfig()
    {
        register(new ContainerLifecycleListener()
        {
            public void onStartup(Container container)
            {
                // access the ServiceLocator here
                serviceLocator = container.getApplicationHandler().getServiceLocator();

                // ... do what you need with ServiceLocator ...
                MyService service = serviceLocator.createAndInitialize(MyService.class);
            }

            public void onReload(Container container) {/*...*/}
            public void onShutdown(Container container) {/*...*/}
        });
    }

    public ServiceLocator getServiceLocator()
    {
        return serviceLocator;
    }
}
```

then elsewhere:

```
MyService service
    = myResourceConfig.getServiceLocator().createAndInitialize(MyService.class);
```

Comment: is this the only way? is there any other way ? accessing container lifecycle seems like an overkill. Thanks

Comment: Another alternative solution is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149161/jersey-and-hk2-servicelocator/21998307#21998307

Comment: What is resource config? and when is this class being called except for the `myResourceConfig.getServiceLocator()`?

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationHandler()' from org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.Container of jersey-core-server  Version: 2.1

Comment: Successfully Changed jersey-core-server  Version to 2.10.4 version.

Comment: Sorry, but onStartup, onReload, onShutdown methods have never invoked.
How to fix it?